# parent negative margin with nested floated divs wont follow the parent if object overlaps

Tags: html, css

Heh, sorry for the long title, but I need a fix for this and have been on it for some time now.

Basically there is a header and I'd like to move content underneath it.
Everything is relative (keeping it centered)
so header has a margin top, z-index, ecc.

The page is relative with a negative margin and contains nested floated columns that wont go up past the header (dammit) and cannot figure out why.

I would like to avoid using absolute positioning if possible.
Here's the code:

```
<div class="header wrapper-standard">
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="inside">hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-wrapper-outer">asda</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="about-page wrapper-standard notop">
    <div class="about-page content">
        <div class="about-block wrapper-long">
            <div class="col col-left text-first">
                asda
            </div>
            <div class="col col-right">
                lol
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-block wrapper-long">
            <div class="col col-left text-first">
                asda
            </div>
            <div class="col col-right">
                lol
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="about-block wrapper-long">
            <div class="col col-left text-first">
                asda
            </div>
            <div class="col col-right">
                lol
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle:
    [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdm43/)

Thanks.

Comment: Just add `float: left` to `.wrapper-standard.notop` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdm43/2/)

Comment: @user2347441 is the red bar and the black bar to remain fixed and have the green and teal content scroll up underneath them?

Comment: @Natalie: that doesn't work.
You can't see it in the example so I have updated the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdm43/3/

The content must flow underneath but stay centered.

Comment: @wf4 yup, see updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example of how you can have a fixed width, centered page with a fixed header which allows the content to flow underneath:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        height:600px;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:400px;
        background-color:#0ff;

    }
    .header_wrapper {
        position:fixed;
        background-color:#ffd800;
    }        

    .header {
        width:400px;
        background-color:#f00;
        height:100px;
    }
    .page {
        padding-top:100px; /*height of header*/
    }    
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header_wrapper">
            <div class="header">Header</div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            Content will be here bla bla etc
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a fiddle so that you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/JjBG5/1/

Comment: Whole purpose is not use absolute/fixed positioning, but thanks

Comment: @grumpyGAMER you mentioned absolute but not fixed - you will not be able to do what you are trying to achieve unless you fix something, its the only way to have the element removed from the flow of the document.

Comment: well, it works with negative margins, but when floats are introduced in the page element, it kidn of breaks.

Comment: Unless you use a script to keep on increasing the negative bottom margin of the header as you scroll, its not going to work I'm afraid. Is there a reason why you can't use fixed? It works in all browsers?

Comment: nah. was more of a proof of concept. Thanks I'll use absolute rather than fixed.